# What am i doing wrong, the code compile, but when i call the create donation function i get invalid opcode. in solidity 0.6.0 everything runs well

Tags: solidity, struct

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Donations {

  struct Donors {
    uint amount;
    address donorAddress;
  }

  struct NewDonation {
    string Name;
    uint  contributors;
    uint  deadline;
    uint unclaimed_deadline ;
    uint  target;
    uint raisedAmount;
    address  owner;
    bool status;
    mapping (uint => Donors) donors;
  }

  NewDonation[] public newdonation;
  uint numDonations;

  function createDonation(string calldata name, address beneficiary, uint _deadline, uint _target) external returns(uint donationID) {
    donationID = numDonations++;
    NewDonation storage d = newdonation[donationID];
    d.Name= name;
    d.deadline =block.timestamp + _deadline;
    d.unclaimed_deadline = _deadline + 300;
    d.target =_target;
    d.owner =  beneficiary;
    d.status =true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `newdonation` is an array

```
NewDonation[] public newdonation;
```

To access an element it has to be a valid position 0 <= position < length.

```
NewDonation storage d = newdonation[donationID];
```

Possible solutions:

1. Make `newdonation` a mapping, all mapping position exists.

   ```
   mapping (uint => NewDonation) public newdonation;
   ```
2. Push elements to the array.

   ```
   // Adds a new element to the end of the array
   NewDonation storage d = newdonation.push();
   // Use array position as ID
   donationID = newdonation.length - 1;
   ```